# EmguCv Ocr failing on easy images

Tags: c#, image, ocr, emgucv

I'm trying to get some numbers from an image using EmguCV C#, and to make things easier I'm filtering the numbers and converting them into a black/white image (Im doing that, because after some tests I saw its a lot more precise like that).

Images its failing to recognize:

[image: First image]

and

[image]

Both images are not been recognized, and its numbers are really clear, not sure, but it shouldn't be a problem for the OCR recognize them, since its recognizing a lot harder images than those.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Tesseract ocr = new Tesseract(Application.StartupPath + "\\tessdata", "eng", OcrEngineMode.Default);
            ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
            ocr.PageSegMode = PageSegMode.SingleLine; //Tested with others types

            Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\debug.png");

            Image<Bgr, Byte> imgg = new Image<Bgr, byte>(img);

            ocr.Recognize(imgg);

            string test = ocr.GetText();

            MessageBox.Show(test);
```

Not sure if there is a way to improve the OCR performance on Emgu, or if I just need to be lucky. Any hint or help will be great, Thank you.